# Program exits right after I type in the input that scanf takes

Tags: c

I am trying to make a diamond shape. I ask the user for a number and then I make a shape of 2n+1 by 2n+1. Instead of the stars I ask for a letter and I print it instead. Also instead of the spaces I print a period. 
My program has stopped running. It asks me for the input then the window just disappears and the program dies. 
I could really use a hint. Yes, this is a homework problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int number_user_Input;
    int temp;
    char letter;
    int shape_dimension;

    printf("Enter a number please: ");
    while((temp=scanf("%d", &number_user_Input))==0)
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]");
        printf("Please enter an actual number:\n");
    }
    if(temp==EOF)
    {
        printf("Nothing to read, number was not found.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You typed: %d\n", number_user_Input);
    }
    printf("Please type only one letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
    shape_dimension = 2*number_user_Input+1;
    printf("Shape dimensions are: %d \n", shape_dimension);
    for(int i=0; i<shape_dimension; i++)
    {
         for(int j=1; j <shape_dimension-i; j++)
        {
           printf(".");
        }
        for(int j=1; j<2*i-1; j++){
            printf("%c", letter);
        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    for(int i=shape_dimension-1; i>=1; i--)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=shape_dimension-i;j++){
            printf(".");
        }
        for(int j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++){
            printf("%c", letter);

        }
        printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: "It asks me for the input then the window just disappears and the program dies." try running it directly from the terminal to see that it actually doesn't output anything before exiting.

Comment: This program [seems working on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nhQgaTPbh96khs6t).

Comment: Why use black magic such as `scanf("%*[^\n]");` when one can use `fgets`/`sscanf`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. especially *before* showing the error message.

Comment: The first `scanf()` leaves `\n` in stdin, which is fetched by the second `scanf()`. that is why it continues to the end.

Comment: `then the window just disappears` - what window? Are you on windows? What "program" are you using to compile and run your source?

Comment: I am using codelite. I am on windows yes.

Comment: @RobertS I think the `\n` will be consumed for the first space in `scanf(" %c", &letter);`.

Comment: I agree that you should run the program in a shell directly instead of running out of some IDE.

Comment: To prevent immediate closing of terminal after program execution finished you could add some `fgets` at the end of your program to wait for another input. But again: running from terminal/shell is suggested solution.

Comment: What do you want to do with `scanf("%*[^\n]");` exactly?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Using `fgets` always leads to code which has problems with too long lines, which then is usually ignored. Why read crap from end of line into buffer, if you can just ignore it?

Comment: Thank you all very much. I fixed it. Weirdly enough but changing the void main() into an int main() and returning zero

Comment: @RobertS Read `scanf` docs to see what `*` and `[` mean in format string

Comment: Please add your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks change for section to this will solve your problem.

```
for(int i=0; i<shape_dimension; i++){
    for(int j=0; j <shape_dimension-i; j++){
        printf(".");
    }

    for(int j=0; j<2*i-1; j++){
        printf("%c", letter);
    }
    printf("\n");

}

//~ printf("\n");

for(int i=shape_dimension; i>=1; i--){

    for(int j=0;j<shape_dimension-i;j++){
        printf(".");
    }

    for(int j=0;j<2*i-1;j++){
        printf("%c", letter);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Run code will produce this output

```
./code <<< "1 a"
Enter a number please: You typed: 1
Please type only one letter: Shape dimensions are: 3 
...
..a
.aaa
aaaaa
.aaa
..a
```

**Other notes**

- `void main()` -> `int main(void)` and `return 0;` at the end  of `main()`.